# Find out which module registered type

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm debugging autofac issues in an application with quite a lot of modules. Is there a way to find out what module registered some registration? I'm looking at the `ComponentRegistry` of the container, but I can't find any information there.

**EDIT:**
A clarification. I have a lot of modules in my solution:

```
public class MyModule : Autofac.Module {
    public override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder) {
        builder.RegisterType<MyConcreteType>().As<IMyInterface>();
    }
}
```

I then register in my container by scanning my assemblies:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(/* Get all assemblies in base dir */);
var container = builder.Build();
```

Now, I have a lot of registrations. My question is "What `Module` registered `MyConcreteType`?". I would like to do something like `container.ComponentRegistry.Registrations.Select(reg => new { reg.Service, reg.RegisteredBy })`, where `RegisteredBy` is some magic property.

Comment: For debugging or at release runtime?

Comment: @Marc: Debugging, if that matters? Is there additional information added in Debug builds?

Comment: One more question: by 'module registered some registration' you mean all modules which are registered as a particular service or all modules which require an injection of a particular service?

Comment: @Marc: Hm, we may be talking about different things? I basically want to know which `Module` implementation called `RegisterType`/whatever, for each registration

Comment: Posted an update, I hope it helps somehow ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I am not a 100% sure what you mean, but I'll give it a go:

For debugging, the implemented type is displayed in the `Registrations` collection of the ComponentRegistry:

[image]

i.e. at index 0, the implementation type is `CustomDataElement`.

As what service type the implementation type is registered can be seen in a `ComponentRegistration`s `Services` collection.

Does that help? Can you give an example otherwise?

**EDIT:**

Got it... Try this:

```
var l = _container.ComponentRegistry.Registrations
    .SelectMany(r => r.Services.OfType<IServiceWithType>(), 
               (r, s) => new { r.Activator.LimitType, s.ServiceType });
```

Not sure whether it works 100% as expected, but it should get you there...

**EDIT 2:**

I misunderstood the question, didn't distinguish between the registered service and the registering module. I don't think it is possible out of the box, as it would either require passing the module as an argument or Autofac to reflect the caller upon registration. Both is not the case, as far as I can tell. I can't find any built in features in Autofac.

If you can modify the modules, one approach would be to register the types with metadata. You probably know the approach, it is something like

```
public class MyModule: Autofac.Module
{
    public override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder) 
    {
        builder.RegisterType<MyConcreteType>()
               .As<IMyInterface>()
               .WithMetadata<IRegisteredByModuleMetadata>(m =>
                    m.For(am => am.RegisteringModuleType, GetType());;
    }
}
```

with the metadata interface

```
public interface IRegisteredByModuleMetadata
{
    Type RegisteringModuleType { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the container, resolving with metadata will allow to access the module types via the registrations `Metadata` property. Depending on your requirements you could simplify the type registration by providing a protected type registration method on a custom module base class which automatically appends the metadata, so you don't have to repeat yourself here.

If modifying every module in your solution is an option, that's probably not a bad way to go. Sorry I can't give any out-of-the-box solution. There might be one, I am missing, but that's all I can do for you here. Hope it helps nonetheless.

Comment: I added some more details in the question. Thanks for your persistence :)

Comment: Sorry about late reply, haven't had time to check this out. Did a quick check in LinqPad now though, and it doesn't seem to be what I want. This will, if I understand it correctly, return all registrations (of some type) with a list of implemented interfaces? It does not provide any data about the `Module`.

Comment: No problem, take your time... r.Activator.LimitType is the concrete type of the module (typeof(MyModule), in your example)...

Comment: Ok, so I tried this out, but the limit type seems to be the actual limit type of the registration? I created a gist of the code I used here: https://gist.github.com/carlpett/9765454, am I missing something?

Comment: You are correct, I misunderstood the question, still. Didn't read the question thoroughly enough, my could returns typeof(MyConcreteType) instead of typeof(MyModule)... I'll update my answer again, though it is not possible out of the box, as far as I can tell...

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I need this for debugging why some things are registered more than once (with different settings...), so I'll do some search-replace and add the metadata for now. Shouldn't be that hard to add in the library, though, I'm guessing? Set some flag during the `RegisterModule` call that is saved during type registrations, more or less. But there may be complications I'm not aware of (and maybe noone else needs this...)

Comment: True, that's another option. Shouldn't be a major problem to extend the library here. It might be a little against the IoC idea: As soon as you rely on information about the registering module, you kind of enforce the configuration of the container via modules. Anyway, for debugging, it would definitely be helpful.